# Ajax example dependent dropdown callback

Tags: hooks, ajax, nodes

I have two custom Drupal modules moduleA and moduleB.
moduleA has all the functions for Ajax calls i.e. `ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback` and `_ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options`.

I create a content type in moduleB called `content_type_b`.
I am using Ajax calls in moduleB to populate drop down in `content_type_b`.

While creating content for `content_type_b`, I try to choose a value from the drop down.
The first time, it works fine. The second time I get an error saying *"An Illegal choice has been selected. Please contact the administrator"*. All these events happen before a node insert.

When I looked into the logs, the hook_node_validate of moduleA is getting called. The node insert must happen in moduleB. So `node_validate` of moduleB must be called. I think since the Ajax functions were present in moduleA, the `node_validate` of moduleA is being called.

Please advice how to proceed in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by changing one of the fields in the Content Type to List(text) instead of node reference. After this the "Illegal choice error" disappeared.